# Remove all rows in .csv except first that feature a duplicate cell in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Due to some regex error I have many rows in a `.csv` file that are the same but with slightly different formatting, the URL is always common variable. I need to find all duplicated of the url in the column "tx" and delete all other than the first one.

`.csv` is ~50k rows. System is Windows.

What I tried:

```
# importing pandas package 
import pandas as pd 

# making data frame from csv file 
data = pd.read_csv("dupes.csv")


# dropping ALL duplicte values 
df = data.drop_duplicates(subset ="TxHash\tx", keep = "first", inplace = True) 

data.to_csv('nodupes.csv', index=False)
```

All columns have /t at the end, unsure how to get rid of them, have also tried numerous variations, including setting new headers with Pandas. Have tried many solutions but most result into this error:

> raise KeyError(diff)
>   KeyError: Index(['TxHash\t'], dtype='object')

Comment: so need `df = data.drop_duplicates(subset ="TxHash\t")` ?

Comment: What return `print (list(data.columns))` ?

Comment: yeah was changing \t round while editing it, have tried all combinations. This is the result of that - ['Buy Token\tBuy Amount\tSell Token\tSell Amount\tMaker\tTaker\tFill\tTxHash']

Comment: Hmm, it seems there is tab separator, so need `data = pd.read_csv("dupes.csv", sep='\t')` and then `df = data.drop_duplicates(subset ="TxHash")`

Comment: Thanks, that solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default separator in `read_csv` is `,`, so for tab is necessary add `sep='\t'` and also for inplace operation is returned `None`, so possible 2 solutions are remove it or not assign back:

```
data = pd.read_csv("dupes.csv", sep='\t')

df = data.drop_duplicates(subset ="TxHash")
print (df)
```

---

```
data.drop_duplicates(subset ="TxHash", inplace=True)
print (data)
```